# How to iteratively construct objects in constructors in C++

Tags: c++

I'm wondering - How does one (in C++) construct iteratively member objects like in an array where there is no default constructor but the arguments are based on a loop value?  Ex: I have a class Space to handle spaces in a rectangular game board:

```
class Space
{
     //...
     const unsigned muiX, muiY;
public:
     Space(const unsigned uiX, const unsigned uiY/*, ...*/);
     // ...
};
```

Then I have a class Board which has a 2D array of Spaces like so:

```
class Board
{
     const static unsigned msuiCols = 20, msuiRows = 20;
     Space mArrBoard[msuiRows][msuiCols];
public:
     Board();
     // ...
};
```

In the CPP, I get an error that I need to initialize mArrBoard and I'm not sure how to initialize it - I've tried inside the function body:

```
for(unsigned uiRowLength = msuiRows, uiRowLoop = 0; uiRowLoop < uiRowLength; uiRowLoop++)
     for(unsigned uiColLength = msuiCols, uiColLoop = 0; uiColLoop < uiColLength; uiColLoop++)
          mArrBoard[uiRowLoop][uiColLoop](uiRowLoop, uiColLoop);
```

but the message I see is that there's no "call" operator defined - when I'm just trying to iteratively call the constructor for Space.  I'd put things in the regular initializers section but I need to change the Row and Column based on a loop so mArrBoard[0][0] == Space(0, 0) soooo...

How do I effect that code though?  I wasn't sure what to search for online or on here to find an answer so I am spelling it out the long way - Sorry for being confusing.

Comment: `mArrBoard[uiRowLoop][uiColLoop](uiRowLoop, uiColLoop)` evaluates `mArrBoard[uiRowLoop][uiColLoop]` and then (if that resolves to a function object or pointer) calls that function with the arguments `uiRowLoop` and `uiColLoop`.   To initialise the array in a constructor, one option is to give `Space` a default constructor (one that accepts no arguments) so all elements of the array are default-initialised while constructing a `Board` and also (e.g. in the body of `Board`s constructor) modify your loop to do `mArrBoard[uiRowLoop][uiColLoop] = Space(uiRowLoop, uiColLoop);`.

Comment: There are 5 standard ways plus some exotic ones: 1. Use a default constructor and set the indices later (disadvantage: uninitialized object lives, class invariant not fulfilled). 2. Use a vector, possibly with reserved size. The vector can grow unlike an array. 3. Use an array of `std::optional<Space>`. Those can be initialized at a later time. 4. If the indices are small, use individual member variables, space00, space01, space11 instead of an array (disadvantage: no easy access with index numbers). 5. Use an array of pointers `std::unique_ptr<Space>`. Those can also be initialized later.

Comment: Side remark: Consider using `std::array` instead of C arrays. They are sometimes safer to use and normally have no overhead at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `std::index_sequence` and delegate constructor, you might do

```
template <std::size_t... Is>
Board(std::index_sequence<Is...>) : mArrBoard{Space(Is / msuiCols, Is % msuiCols)...} {}

Board() : Board(std::make_index_sequence<msuiCols * msuiRows>()) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

std::vector all the way:

```
#include <vector>

class Board
{
    std::vector<std::vector<Space>> mArrBoard;
    const static unsigned msuiCols = 20, msuiRows = 20;
public:
    Board()
    {
        mArrBoard.resize(msuiRows);
        for (unsigned row = 0; row < msuiRows; row++)
        {
            mArrBoard[row].reserve(msuiCols);  // optional, but makes subsequent appends more efficient.
            for (unsigned col = 0; col < msuiCols; col++)
            {
                mArrBoard[row].emplace_back(row, col);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Afterwords, you can access any item in mArrBoard the same way as you would if it was a 2-d array:

```
Space& space = mArrBoard[10][5];
space.doSomething(a,b,c);
```

Otherwise, the alternative is to have a default constructor for Space and an `init` function called for each item in the Board constructor.

Comment: It would be more efficient to use a 1D vector than to use a sparse 2D vector. Calculating 2D indexes into a 1D array is trivial

Comment: @RemyLebeau - it could also be coded in assembly. :)

Comment: @ selbie why resize only for the rows? @RemyLebeau That is no `sparse` vector, there are no gaps.

Comment: @Sebastian - Invoking `resize` on an individual row would require that the vector instantiate instances of Space for each one using the default constructor. Since Space doesn't have a default constructor.... I updated the code above to invoke `.reserve()` on each row as optimization to the vector doesn't continually resize and re-copy items.

Comment: @Sebastian I say sparse because a `vector<vector>` is not stored contiguously in memory, the elements are all over the place. Unlike a single `vector`, which is contiguous.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Okay, and each of the inner vectors can have a different size, too.